# Alsa C library example - why don't free() malloced buffer?

Tags: c, api, alsa

I am porting my application from portaudio to pure alsa api.
I checked some examples and don't understand why nobody frees buffer allocated with malloc() for snd_pcm_readi()?
As an example we have simple test program latency.c from www.alsa-project.org:
[latency.c](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/_2test_2latency_8c-example.html)
Why there is no free(buffer) at the end of the program?

Comment: That buffer is `malloc`ed in `main` and needs to persist until the end of `main`. There is no need to `free` memory at the end of `main` because the process ends and the operating system takes back all the memory allocated to that process anyway. Do you have a different example where this is not the case or does this answer your question?

Comment: I know that, but in my test case when I do at the and free(buffer) then I got double free or other corruption. Now I found bug in my tests. I malloced not enough memory for readi frames. (I forgot to multiply frames count per chunk size (sizeof(int32_t)). When I allocate right size for buffer then I can free it without corruption.